# Formcontrol bindings not working for a specific formGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have reactive form and see null values for formcontrols under alternate formGroup. As you can see in the markup below , I have added the attribute [formGroupName]="alternate" but it doesn't seem to work.
I had also tried formGroupName="alternate".  So the formControls outside alternate are bound correctly to be clear but not the ones under alternate. There is some issue with the bindings.Could you let me know what the problem is ?

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.languageService.alternateLanguageSelected$.subscribe(alternateLanguageSelected => {
      this.alternateLanguageSelected = alternateLanguageSelected;
    });

    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      yesNoMultilingualPrincipalAddress: [{ value: false, disabled: this.readonly }],
      yesNoMultilingualMailingAddress: [{ value: false, disabled: this.readonly }],
      yesNoOtherBusinessAddresses: [{ value: false, disabled: this.readonly }],
      hasDifferentPrincipalAddress: [{ value: null, disabled: this.readonly }, Validators.required],
      differentPrincipalAddress: [
        { value: null, disabled: this.readonly },
        [conditionalValidator(() => this.form.hasDifferentPrincipalAddress.value, requiredAddress)]
      ],
      

      alternate: this.formBuilder.group({
        hasDifferentPrincipalAddress: [{ value: null, disabled: this.readonly }],
        differentPrincipalAddress: [{ value: null, disabled: this.readonly }],      
      }),
    });
    }
    
    
    
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" novalidate>       
    <div class="flex-group">
        <div class="flex-2">
    
          <fieldset class="boxed">
            <legend translate for="hasDifferentPrincipalAddress">details.main-address</legend>
            <app-yes-no [ngClass]="{ submitted: submitted }" name="hasDifferentPrincipalAddress"
              formControlName="hasDifferentPrincipalAddress"></app-yes-no>
            <aa-alert alertClass="error" alertText="{{ 'common.required' | translate }}"
              *ngIf="(form.hasDifferentPrincipalAddress.touched || submitted) && form.hasDifferentPrincipalAddress.errors?.required">
            </aa-alert>
          </fieldset>
    
          <div class="field boxed" *ngIf="this.alternateLanguageSelected && form.hasDifferentPrincipalAddress.value">
            <app-yes-no-multilingual name="yesNoMultilingualPrincipalAddress"
              formControlName="yesNoMultilingualPrincipalAddress" id="yesNoMultilingualPrincipalAddress"
              [description]="'common.yesno-multilingual-text'">
            </app-yes-no-multilingual>
          </div>
    
          <div class="field dependant" *ngIf="form.hasDifferentPrincipalAddress.value">
            <div class="field">
              <app-address formControlName="differentPrincipalAddress" [submitted]="submitted" [englishOnly]="true"></app-address>
            </div>
          </div>
    
         </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="flex-2">
          <fieldset class="boxed" *ngIf="form.yesNoMultilingualPrincipalAddress.value">
            <legend translate for="hasDifferentPrincipalAddress">details.main-address</legend>
            <app-yes-no [ngClass]="{ submitted: submitted }" name="hasDifferentPrincipalAddress" [formGroupName]="alternate"
              formControlName="hasDifferentPrincipalAddress"></app-yes-no>
          </fieldset>
    
          <div class="field dependant" *ngIf="form.yesNoMultilingualPrincipalAddress.value">
            <div class="field">
              <app-address formControlName="differentPrincipalAddress" [submitted]="submitted" [formGroupName]="alternate"
                [showAlternateLanguageFields]="form.yesNoMultilingualPrincipalAddress.value"></app-address>
            </div>
          </div>
    
        
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `formGroupName="alternate"` at `<div class="flex-2">` .

```
<div class="flex-2" formGroupName="alternate" >
  <fieldset class="boxed" *ngIf="form.yesNoMultilingualPrincipalAddress.value">
    <legend translate for="hasDifferentPrincipalAddress">details.main-address</legend>
    <app-yes-no [ngClass]="{ submitted: submitted }" name="hasDifferentPrincipalAddress"
      formControlName="hasDifferentPrincipalAddress"></app-yes-no>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="field dependant" *ngIf="form.yesNoMultilingualPrincipalAddress.value">
    <div class="field">
      <app-address formControlName="differentPrincipalAddress" [submitted]="submitted"
        [showAlternateLanguageFields]="form.yesNoMultilingualPrincipalAddress.value"></app-address>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I already have that tag but forgot to mention in my post. I have just updated the post. So the formControls outside alternate are bound correctly to be clear but not the ones under alternate

Comment: If I do that then will the following control that belongs to the parent form work ? *ngIf="form.yesNoMultilingualPrincipalAddress.value

Comment: `form` in the HTML refers the `form` variable in the script. It looks your script does not have the variable `form`. Is it typo of `formGroup`?